# Hot to edit all columns in phpMyAdmin

Tags: phpmyadmin

One column has more than 500 rows and I need to change that content in each column where the column is. How can I do it?

[Each row in the column in the square must be edited and replaced by 1 instead of 3.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OTPWT.jpg)

Comment: With an `UPDATE` query? ... what is the issue?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.